# Android DrawerLayout Covering Up LinearLayout In XML Preview

Tags: android

I have implemented a Navigation Drawer which works fine however whenever I need to go back and add/edit my activity buttons/textviews (any widget) I have to remove this code first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

because it is the root layout and it covers up my child LinearLayout which has widgets (see attached below image).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfpJd.jpg): [image: description]

How can I uncover my LinearLayout contents while still keeping the DrawerLayout code, it's just tiring to have to remove it and edit my widgets visually and then add it back when I'm done.

Comment: usually you should use separate layout when using navigationview, one for navigation view and other for contents.

Comment: do I need to use Fragments for that?

Comment: Not specific but if you need separate screen then yes.